# HTTP timed request Golang

Tags: go

I'm new to Go and  trying to generate multiple requests to several http/ https servers to check the response time and the status of each web server.

I stored the URLs in a text file, afterwards I decided to add a ticker to my code which will keep generating these requests on each URL after a certain amount of time (the amount of time is in seconds typed next to each URL and spaced with a tab).

When I started scanning the time from the file everything got complicated and I can't manage to find my mistake. Here is my Go code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func get_resp_time(url string) { //Get time for each URL

    time_start := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("Start time", time_start, " URL ", url)
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    //fmt.Printf("resp : %#v \n", resp)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error fetching: %v", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println(time.Since(time_start), url, " Status: ", resp.Status)
}

func main() {
    content, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("url_list.txt")
    lines := strings.Split(string(content), "\t")
    //fields := strings.Split(string(content), "\t")
    //fmt.Println(lines[1])
    //fmt.Println(strconv.Atoi(lines[0]))

    const workers = 25
    var nb int

    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    in := make(chan string, 2*workers)

    if _, err := strconv.Atoi(lines[1]); err == nil {
        nb, err = strconv.Atoi(lines[1])
    }

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * time.Duration(nb))

    for t := range ticker.C {
        fmt.Println("Time of origin: ", time.Now())
        for i := 0; i < len(lines)-1; i++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                defer wg.Done()
                //for j := 0; j < len(in); j++ {
                if _, err := strconv.Atoi(lines[i]); err == nil {
                    nb, err = strconv.Atoi(lines[i])
                    //get_resp_time(url)
                } else {
                    get_resp_time(lines[i])
                }

                //}
            }()
        }
        for _, url := range lines {
            if url != "" {
                in <- url
            }
        }
        fmt.Println("Tick at ", t)
    }
    close(in)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

And the text file:

```
http://google.com   5   
http://nike.com     10
```

This is the error I got:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x2752]

goroutine 9 [running]:
panic(0x313180, 0xc82000a0d0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:464 +0x3e6
main.get_resp_time(0xc82006e195, 0x14)
    /Users/Elliott/Desktop/GoTutorial/url-time-response.go:26 +0x712
main.main.func1(0xc820070dc0, 0xc82006e1e0, 0xc8200a0090, 0x9, 0x9, 0xc820070da8)
    /Users/Elliott/Desktop/GoTutorial/url-time-response.go:61 +0x13f
created by main.main
    /Users/Elliott/Desktop/GoTutorial/url-time-response.go:65 +0x4a6
exit status 2
```

EDIT: Alright, I just changed the file to having only one duration because apparently it's pretty complicated to have multiple duration(according to my project advisor). Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to describe "everything got complicated".  Show an error or stack trace...we need something to work with.

Comment: Here is what I'm getting after running the code: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x2752]
The rest is related to the goroutine but I expect it to work once my issue is solved. It might be related to one of my loops I'm pretty positive about it.

Comment: Could you put the error in the question so it is formatted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't appear to be parsing your file correctly.  You should first split on `\n`, THEN split on `\t`.  Also, verify your text file actually has `\t` and not spaces.

You should probably iterate through your parsed values with `fmt.Println` to verify your parsed results are as expected.

It should look something like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/B1qIDZnZ81).

Comment: Thanks for answering, yeah the file is separated by tabs and when I print the values they show up as expected.

Comment: I tried to do this but now I'm getting this error: cannot convert lines (type []string) to type string. Regarding the second split on \t. PS: I updated the code with the error you requested earlier.

Comment: That error means you are trying to use the entire string array as a string.  You'll need to iterate over it or otherwise handle only one line at a time.  See my updated answer with a link.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out yesterday after some research but I crashed to sleep. But your code is giving the same error I had. Sorry for bothering.